# Laravel 8 .env file automatically empty in sometimes

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

Sometimes `.env` file cleared automatically. I gave all `Read / Write` permission for `.env` file.

Note: It happened after upgrade the Laravel version 7.x to 8.x

**Laravel version : 8**

**PHP version : 7.4**

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain a little bit when it is cleared automatically? Like working on which part or anything

Comment: @VijayRana in localhost - working (Not every time ). In server - any files upload (Not every time )

Comment: If this is happening right now in production, I recommend you 100% to remove write permission from that file from everyone, so only `root` can edit the file.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Restricted the write permission means. I can't update the admin settings values ( like SMTP details ) in my .env file.

Comment: You have to set permission level `644`

Comment: @Siva how can't you ? Don't you have `root` access ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I want to dynamically update the .env file values based on website admin settings.

Comment: @Siva how are you doing so ? With Laravel using a commands ? Is it an external program ? How are you doing it ? Maybe that is the problem and is cleared automatically. But also, let me tell you, that updating a `.env` "dynamically" is super weird. Can you explain more ?